# jQuery function for more than one image preview before upload

Tags: jquery

I'm using more than one `<input type="file">` tag in my page with same class="inputFile" as shown below

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <form id="form2" runat="server">
    <input type='file' class="inputFile" />
    <img class="image_upload_preview" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="your image" />
  </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
  <form id="form3" runat="server">
    <input type='file' class="inputFile" />
    <img class="image_upload_preview" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="your image" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I want to show the preview of the image when I select an image, and I'm using jQuery function for that.

```
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('.image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
  $(".inputFile").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });
```

This code is working fine, but when I'm choosing an image for the first tag, it is selecting the same image for both fields as below:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to amend your `readURL` function to traverse the DOM to find the `.image_upload_preview` element related to the current `input`. Try this:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $(input).next('.image_upload_preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$(".inputFile").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
});
```

Note the use of `$(input).next('.image_upload_preview')`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target associated preview image tag as follows:

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var upload_preview = $(input).closest("form").find(".image_upload_preview");
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            upload_preview.attr('src', e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
  $(".inputFile").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });
```